# macOS: Add VSCode to path

Tags: macos, bash, mac, macos-mojave

Despite the fact that I have taken care of this:

```
pkaramol@MacBook-Pro bin $ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

and also ..

```
 pkaramol@MacBook-Pro bin $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/Caskroom/docker/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

`code` executable is still not available:

```
pkaramol@MacBook-Pro bin $ which code
pkaramol@MacBook-Probin $ code
-bash: code: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You added the executable `code` to your `PATH` statement.

`/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`

You want to specify the bin directory.  Change the `/etc/paths` from:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

to by dropping the `/code`.

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
```

VSCode will do this for you.  In VSCode type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> which will bring up the Command Palette.

Then type <kbd>shell command</kbd> and you'll see an entry for **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command**

Execute that command it the magic will happen for you.